# Convert Oracle relation string to POSTGIS dimensional matrix

Tags: computational-geometry, postgis, oracle-spatial

I want to convert a query from Oracle spatial to postgis. It uses relation strings for it's sdo_relate function for which I want to get the dimensional matrix in st_relate. I tried using st_intersects, but I get overlapping areas in geometries. Can I please get some help in understanding the conversion? Thanks.

I want the postgis dimensional matrix for the following two oracle relation strings-

```
st_relate(geomA, geomB, 'MASK=ANYINTERACT')

st_relate(geomA, geomB, 'mask=TOUCH+INSIDE')
```

Answer (score 1):

ST_Intersects(A,B) and ST_Contains(A,B), respectively.

Comment: thanks. the overlap didn't go by replacing st_intersects(a,b) with st_contains(a,b). Also, there were some additional unexpected lines. Could it be because st_contains only does 'inside' and not 'touch'?